# I want to calculate the electric field of a charged solid sphere without using Gauss's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, coulombs-law

I can find the electric field from a charged solid sphere using Gauss's law but I am struggling to calculate this from Coulomb's law (I have seen examples of calculating e-field using Coulomb's law for a disk, a ring, a line etc. but not a solid sphere).

If anyone could help me out I would be very grateful!

Comment: Gauß' law and Coulomb's law are equivalent, i.e. one can be derived from the other. I therefore don't understand what it means to calculate something with the use of Coulomb's law but not of Gauß' law.

Comment: @ACuriousMind maybe solving Poisson's equation would qualify?

Comment: I think you can sum disks up to a sphere. Personally, unless you are not familiar with how to calculate stuffs with the Coulomb's law, I see no reason why bother yourself with it - we have mathematica now.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I think that the OP is talking about finding the intensity using "traditional method" of taking elements and using integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me clarify something. I think what you mean by "Coulomb's law" is the solution to the electrostatic Poisson equation with the assumption (boundary condition) that it vanishes at spatial infinity:

$$V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|}d^3\mathbf{r}'$$

You can get the electric field by taking the negative gradient of this.
$$\rightarrow\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=-\nabla V(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')\mathbf{r}'}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}'|^3}d^3\mathbf{r}'$$

When the only charge you have is a point charge sitting at the origin ($\rho(\mathbf{r'})=Q\delta^3(\mathbf{r}')$, where $\delta^3(\mathbf{r})$ is the 3-dimensional Dirac-delta function), then you get the regular Coulomb's law.

$$\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q\mathbf{r}}{|\mathbf{r}|^3}$$

Now, for your problem, simply using Gauss's law will do. Gauss's law says

$$\iint\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0}$$

Since you know the problem is spherically symmetric, not only can the electric field can **only** point radially outwards (prove this to yourself), but it is also spherically symmetric (also prove this to yourself). So, Gauss's law reduces to

$$E(r)\cdot(4\pi r^2)=\frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0},~~~\textrm{where}~~~ \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})=E(r)\hat{r}$$

To solve for the electric field, you must calculate the charge enclosed within your "Gaussian surface", and for that you must know the charge distribution within the sphere.

$$Q_{enc}(r)=\int_0^r \rho(r')(4\pi r^2) dr$$

For example, if the solid sphere of radius $R$ and charge $Q$ has a uniform charge density, then the total amount of charge within the spherical Gaussian surface with radius $r<R$ scales with the cube of the radius - i.e. $Q_{enc}=Q(r^3/R^3)$. In that case,

$$E(r)=\frac{Qr}{4\pi\epsilon_0 R^3},~~~r<R$$

For a spherical Gaussian surface with radius $r>R$, all the charge $Q$ is inside, so we simply get

$$E(r)=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}, ~~~r\geq R$$

Answer (score 3):

[image: Integration to find Electric field of solid sphere]

Following on from Arturo's answer (thanks) I think I have figured out how to solve the integration over the sphere to find the electric field at a point using spherical coordinates and vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Electric field by uniformly charged solid sphere using Coulomb's Law and not Gauss' Law

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE. On this site, we prefer that authors post their content in text form, and not as a clicked image of text written on paper. Can you please edit(type) this information into your answer, using "edit" button you see under your post? Thanks. :)